# powershell get listening tcp sockets

Tags: networking, powershell

I'm looking for some way to list the open sockets on a (local) machine. In particular I'd like to get the listening tcp socket addresses. (Much like the info from netstat.exe - but in a powershell "hative" way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get-Netstat](http://poshcode.org/560) is a Powershell script that has been written to run netstat, and objectivise its output - creating a Powershell object with this all the information from a netstat command.